# jquery timeago NaN years ago with ISO date format

Tags: jquery, timeago

I have some issues with jQuery timeago plugin http://timeago.yarp.com/

First of all, the short call version doesn't works, I don't know why.
`$("#abbr.timeago").timeago();` displays nothing. I must use `$("abbr.timeago").text($.timeago($(this).prop("title")));` Weird...

(called in $(document).ready...)

Anyway, timeago allways displays me a 'NaN years ago'. Here are some generated html tag with differents formats

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
`<abbr class="timeago" title="2013-04-17T11:32:08Z">NaN years ago</abbr>`

...HH:mm:ssZ" displays
`<abbr class="timeago" title="2013-04-17T11:32:08+0100">NaN years ago</abbr>`

"...HH:mm:ssZ" displays
`<abbr class="timeago" title="2013-04-17T11:32:08CEST">NaN years ago</abbr>`

"...HH:mm:ss" displays
`<abbr class="timeago" title="2013-04-17T11:32:08">NaN years ago</abbr>`

Can anyone tell what format should I use ? and, is the `<abbr>` tag required ?

Jquery 1.10.2, timeago 1.1.0, chrome 26

Thanks !

Comment: *"First of all, the short call version doesn't works, I don't know why. `$("#abbr.timeago").timeago();`"* You've used an ID selector there, which I'm guessing you didn't want.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/alepav/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/alepav/1/edit) That's with v1.9.1. Also works with v1.9.2-pre (http://jsbin.com/alepav/2/edit). Not sure where you're getting 1.10.2? Also works with 2.0.0b2 (http://jsbin.com/alepav/3/edit).

Comment: Thanks TJ. Forget about the sharp, I must have added it for testing, but it doesn't work even without it. I can see that you are in GMT and write your date directly in the abbr. So I guess the problem comes from the format I used and its generated string, or timezone...

Comment: Refresh the whole solution, clear caches, F5... It works ! O_O